# Casting Kotlin ArrayLists ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin

I have a `MutableList<Card>` called `cards` that I am sorting based on one of the properties, using the `sortedWith` function. This returns a sorted generic list type, so a cast is necessary. However, when I cast the list, it crashes with a ClassCastException:

```
private var cards: MutableList<Card> = ArrayList()
...
cards = cards.sortedWith(compareBy{it.face}) as ArrayList<Card>



java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

EDIT: I just realized I need to use the more generic type of cards for the cast, `MutableList<Card>`. Now, can someone explain why the cast with ArrayList fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast fails because the list returned by `sortedWith` function is not an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`.

Moreover it's unsafe to cast it to `MutableList` too, because the implementation of `sortedWith` can be changed later, so that it returns `List` that's no longer a `MutableList`.

If you have a `MutableList` and you want to sort it, you have two options:

- either sort it in-place with the `sortWith` function (not `sortedWith`):

  ```
  cards.sortWith(compareBy{it.face})
  // now cards list is sorted
  ```
- or sort it to a new list and then copy it to a mutable list, if you need to mutate it after

  ```
  cards = cards.sortedWith(compareBy{it.face}).toMutableList()
  ```

Comment: Thanks, sorting it in place is a much better option. What is the difference between sorting in place with sortWith and sortBy?

Comment: @GusW `sortBy { }` is a shortcut for `sortWith(compareBy { })`. Better to ask as a separate question, and you'll get a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to sort a list in place without creating a new one and assign back to the original. The simplest is `cards.sortBy { it.face }`